# VS Code Cannot Detect Java Libraries

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, import, importerror

I recently downloaded VS Code for Java development. When I initially opened an existing Java Project in VS Code, it was unable to identify objects from the Selenium library. I downloaded the Java Extensions plugin and a few others, and now VS code will not recognize any of my imports as valid. Javax and Java.swing are among the now undetectable libraries. Is there a setting I missed? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

VSCode just an Editor, after you install some extensions, it only makes the editor more convenient, get more abilities even can help you develop the project of some kind of language through combine with the language support in your computer. Such as, you need to install JDK, then to install the 'Java' extension, then the extension to combine with the JDK and the VSCode, then you will get the ability to develop java project in VSCode.

That's means, The 'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat' has nothing to do with java development. For example, after you install the JDK on your computer, you can develop java projects in the other IDEAs such as Intellij IDEA or some others. The 'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat' extension just to combine the JDK with VSCode better, to make VSCode better to develop java project.

As you said, you failed to import libraries. Of course, the 'Java' extension without any libraries of java. You need to configure it by yourself. In the Explorer panel, you can find 'JAVA PROJECTS'. In it, you can find which libraries you have referenced and you can adds libraries in it. And of course, you'd better take maven to manage your project.

By the way, recommend you to install 'Java Extension Pack' extension.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to [add support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) through [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) because by default VS Code does not support Java. The great thing about this extension is that you get a slue of other extensions as well, such as; maven, debugging tools, support for junit, auto completion, etcetera.

On a side note, you could always use an IDE/IDEA like IntelliJ, Eclipse, or likewise. I'm definitely partial to IntelliJ but they all have their pro's and con's.

Comment: I downloaded RedHat's extension for Java support. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: Well, the great thing about that extension is that you get a slue of other extensions as well, such as; maven, debugging tools, support for junit, auto completion, etcetera.

Comment: I used Eclipse before, and moved to VS so that I could do all of my coding in one place. Now, despite having downloaded a boatload of extensions, apparently none of my java libraries exist, and Eclipse won't reopen the project

Comment: That is likely due to the maven support. You're going to have to define your dependencies in a `project object model` or `POM` file. I'd definitely suggest giving IntelliJ a go if you haven't. This is subjective but It's a really clean tool.